# Background image only being displayed once

Tags: css, html, background-image, repeat

I have a strange problem that I can't get my head around:

I have a header div and I would like to display a background image to be repeated horizontally:

The HTML:

```
<div id="headerwrapper">

     <div id="header">
          <p>This is an extremely interesting test. This is an extremely interesting test. This is an extremely interesting test.</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#headerwrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:630px;    
}

#header {
    width:630px;
    background-image:url(../images/headermiddleback.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

When I look at it in the browser, I can see only 1 instance of the background-image being displayed above the text. But it is not repeating.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you make a real demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bTuzA/ - seems to work.. Do you have any other CSS that might be overwriting this?

Comment: Hmm interesting, but for example I want the background image to be displayed under each other, not side by side. Am I using the wrong css for "repeat"?

Comment: yes - for vertical repeat use `repeat-y` instead of `repeat-x` - http://jsfiddle.net/bTuzA/1/

Comment: Here is what I am getting http://jsfiddle.net/partisanentity/hsTPU/

Comment: `repeat-y` - http://jsfiddle.net/hsTPU/4/  and you don't need the `clear: both`-s

Comment: PartisanEntity, what do you *want* to get? Your example looks working to me.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: that was it, please post this as a proper answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `repeat-y` instead of `repeat-x`

```css
#header {
    width:630px;
    background-image:url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4457768/css/headermiddleback.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example on jsFiddle, seems to be working. 
http://jsfiddle.net/MgvLT/1/

Perhaps you have some other CSS that's getting into the way or maybe your background image has lots of empty space. Please post your example on jsFiddle.

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is working perfectly for me (using Google Chrome). I tried increasing the width of #header so I can see if background image gets repeated and it does. What browser are you using?

Comment: Strange, I am using FF 12.0 on Mac

Comment: I just emptied the cache, and still it's not working. Could this have something to do with the fact that it is running off a MAMP instance on my Mac?

Comment: MAMP should have nothing to do with it. Are you sure you really want `repeat-x` instead of `repeat-y` as suggested above?

Comment: Check the above [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsTPU/4/). I believe this is a case of mistaking horizontal repeat for vertical repeat.

Comment: Oh my God. You guys are right. I'm so sorry, in shame I must admit I have been trying to get this to work for the past hour and never even considered that I mixed up x and y... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to **clear** your browsers **cache**?

For example, here's a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/1195891) showing how to do it for Chrome.